# Best practice for error codes in batch processing?

Tags: batch-processing, exit-code

I have a CLI tool that processes a bunch of objects, and I would like to use the exit code to signal whether everything worked well or not.

Now, if everything is fine I return `0`. This is pretty simply and obvious.

But what do I do if one of the processed objects fails? Should I simply return a `1`, which then effectively means "Something went wrong"? Or should I return the number of failed objects as an error code?

The problem here is that I am not sure about the semantics of the error code: Basically it would be interesting to know how many objects have failed, but on the other hand this means that I can not distinguish different errors from each other, because the error code is not related any longer to the actual type of the error.

Are the any best practices on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Return 1 and put logs in some place that are readable by computer and human (CSV is good option) is in my opinion best what you can do.
But if you exactly know types of errors that can happen, you can use them as a [masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) so you will and up with something that you can decode and knew which errors occurred but without it's count.